# How to get index number of pandas data frame that contain only null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-preprocessing

Consider the below data frame.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkSBF.png)

I want to extract the ids of this dataframe that contain only null values.
For example, id 1 has only null values. So the answer should be index 1. Can you please explain how to extract this?

Please note that I do not want ids that contain partial null values, for instance, IDs 0 and 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) :

```
m = df.isnull().all(axis=1)

L = list(df[m].index)

print(L)
#[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like the follow:

```
null_row = df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)].index
```

1. `isnull()` is a function that checks for the empty values
2. `all` considers all things depending on the parameter(check the below)
3. `axis=1` refers to the columns
4. `index` is for getting index number

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to find *all* rows and [`.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to find *any* rows (where axis=1 gives you rows).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Clm1": ['A', np.nan, 'C', np.nan],
        "Clm2": [20.0, np.nan, 19.0, np.nan],
        "Clm3": [np.nan, np.nan, 'X', 'Y'],
    }
)

ans = df[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
print(list(ans.index))
[1]
```